# Samsung Smart TV video player App - Access mp4 stored on USB

Tags: javascript, video, usb, filepath, samsung-smart-tv

I have developed a video player App using the AVPlayer (with Samsungs webapi) and the project is setup as a Samsung Smart TV Javascript Project. 
Right now I can play any video from the web (from any url), but I can't access any local files from the USB storage or a hard drive that is connected to the Smart TV.

I am using the Samsung Smart TV SDK 5.1

Is there some kind of Samsung Library that I have to import?

I tried using the loader.js script in my index.html, but it didn't work for me.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/af/2.0.0/loader.js"></script>
```

Could it be that I have to change my project from the Javascript Project into a Apps Framework Project in order to use the functionalities from the loader.js?

edit:
thank you alfredo86. I can get an array of my files that are stored on the usb drive. Is there a possibility to read those files from the array and hand them to a src tag? Or is there a possibility to read a xml file now from the usb? I found openFile() in the Samsung File API, but it says that

openFile() is only able to ‘read’ files in directory where an application is installed
but i would like to read a xml from the usb drive

Comment: i am looking for such app ! What is the name of it so i find it in samsung hub app store?

Answer (score 1):

you access data from the USB

load object with class clsid:SAMSUNG-INFOLINK-STORAGE

here is a little bit debated
http://samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/a56519250d733296?forumID=0c7ddcbe3a1811af

I hope it is helpful for you... If you have some questions you are welcome

Comment: do I understand it right that you are talking about an app which is running on TV set, right? Do you have a hint how to create an android app which would play files from USB stick (connected to the TV)?

Comment: Android app? Do you mean app on Philips or Sony TV with Android? Or do you mean TV app with remote controller in Android phone?

Comment: The latter: TV app with remote controller in Android phone. If you can give me a bit guidance on this one, please contact me on asedelnikov@appmagnetics.de, we will then also discuss conditions on collaboration